# How to compare two integers and get a bool answer

Tags: c#, sql, bit-manipulation

I need to compare 2 long integers and get a Boolean value.

In SQL I'd do:

```
long1 & long2 <> 0
```

this would evaluate to either true or false
like this:

```
9 & 4 <> 0 is true
5 & 12 <> 0 is false
```

How do I do that in C#?

Comment: 9 & 4 <> 0 will evaluate to false because bit wise AND of 9 and 4 is zero. Similarly 5 & 12 <> 0 will evaluate to true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's similar in C#.

```
long1 & long2 != 0
```

In C#, `&&` is logical AND and `&` is bitwise AND. Similarly `||` is logical OR and `|` is bitwise.

Comment: @gunr2171 I believe the author wants it to be bit-wise.

Comment: Also, `^` is bitwise XOR, and `~` is bitwise NOT.